# iCloud Drive/Dropbox based media player app (or similar)?

Tags: ios, media-player, dropbox

Is there an audio player app which makes it easy to quickly add some files to an iOS device which does not require a lengthy import and sync via iTunes? The only thing in this category I could find is [SimplePlay](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simpleplay/id518444097?mt=8), which gets the job done, but really is very version 0.1 and abandoned.

Ideally the player would simply play anything from iCloud Drive, alternatively Dropbox, alternatively any other mechanism that is convenient to move files onto the device. No "library" type of organisational scheme required or wanted, just pure files will do. The reason for not always wanting to use iTunes is simply that I do not necessarily want to import all sorts of non-music files into my library, or that I may not actually be at my main iTunes machine and hence cannot sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year later, and I've discovered [CloudBeats](https://appsto.re/nl/ehxMO.i). Works pretty much exactly as I wanted, except that iCloud is not supported, but a ton of alternatives including Dropbox are.

Answer (score 1):

vlc media player now supports it:

[image]